# Adjust TForm to Current

Tags: screen, lazarus, freepascal

After I had finished a tool I made in FreePascal (using Lazarus IDE), I gave it to a few people to use (and test) it. Some of my friends have 1080p-monitors, some have 2160p monitors while one still has an 720p Monitor. My Problem is, that the tool is too big (talking about size of UI not filesize) for the 720p monitor but could be too small for people with higher monitors (2160p).

The goal for my "update" would be to set custom sizes based on the screen-resolution.
For example both the length and width should be about 41,67%. The Buttons and Images should be sized as well.

I initially set a static Form Size for a 2160p Montitor before I have re-written it for a 1440p monitor.
In the first version for the 2160p Monitor I set the Form of the UI to 1600x900 (which were 41,67% of the resolution).

I don't have any idea on how to do this.
The only code I have so far is this procedure which places the tool in the middle of the screen (since I had my fair share of problems with that, too):

```
    procedure TForm1.staticView();
    var
       w : Integer;
       h : Integer;
    begin
       Form1.position := poDeskTopCenter;
       Form1.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
       
       w := Screen.Height;
       h := Screen.Width;   
    end;
```

Not sure if I need to initalize Screen.Heght and .Width and how to propperly set custom TForm and TButton sizes.